# How to find string pattern in python

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, search

I have a large string (called LargeSTR) which has multiple instances of the following patterns:

```
{"location": {"latitude": 34.04481184664412, "longitude": -118.30783339686604},
```

in each instance, the values of latitude and longitude could be different, how I can extract these latitude and longitude data from this large string by search for a pattern. here is an example of LargSTR

```
, "hovercard_id": "1Lm6ExY6B8v9E6B09j5h6w", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 0], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 0], "size": [24, 32]}}, "22": {"url": "/biz/la-barca-restaurant-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.0339201576781, "longitude": -118.29148504989}, "key": 22, "hovercard_id": "B68Kl37vf9qF7GImxhELkQ", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 32], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 32], "size": [24, 32]}}, "23": {"url": "/biz/el-migueleno-restaurant-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.0350506, "longitude": -118.2915704}, "key": 23, "hovercard_id": "y3815rRI1BP66oq09m6TjQ", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 64], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 64], "size": [24, 32]}}, "24": {"url": "/biz/house-of-curry-los-angeles-4", "location": {"latitude": 34.040289, "longitude": -118.3086312}, "key": 24, "hovercard_id": "SoisYg5oSRA5eiBl0wPALg", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 96], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 96], "size": [24, 32]}}, "25": {"url": "/biz/ebaes-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.0343956, "longitude": -118.2836649}, "key": 25, "hovercard_id": "Tnc0HTOhLEWEXAPBjH5u7w", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 128], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 128], "size": [24, 32]}}, "26": {"url": "/biz/belizean-fish-market-los-angeles-2", "location": {"latitude": 34.0314363, "longitude": -118.3087631}, "key": 26, "hovercard_id": "NnO4zEpZt3MvzYFU_MrXaQ", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 160], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 160], "size": [24, 32]}}, "27": {"url": "/biz/omars-hot-dog-stand-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.0286688, "longitude": -118.2915386}, "key": 27, "hovercard_id": "9hcR6H1PePDMB_JziH7VSA", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 192], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 192], "size": [24, 32]}}, "28": {"url": "/biz/bacaro-la-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.034478, "longitude": -118.28342}, "key": 28, "hovercard_id": "0UCg5MwkhM4Qj1GnFdXBFA", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 224], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 224], "size": [24, 32]}}, "29": {"url": "/biz/teds-burger-3-los-angeles", "location": {"latitude": 34.0258372, "longitude": -118.3005593}, "key": 29, "hovercard_id": "eETHUFJ7cCC8mrQGUiJMpQ", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 256], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 256], "size": [24, 32]}}, "30": {"url": "/biz/study-hall-los-angeles-3", "location": {"latitude": 34.028543, "longitude": -118.284365}, "key": 30, "hovercard_id": "nrgJNUjt0vNF7TrhmWMtiw", "resource_type": "business", "icon": {"regular_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "scaled_size": [48, 320], "anchor_offset": [12, 32], "name": "business", "active_origin": [24, 288], "active_uri": "https://media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/mapmarkers/yelp_map_range/20160801/21/30.png", "regular_origin": [0, 288], "size": [24, 32]}}}, "top_biz_bounds": null, "hoods": [{"highlighted": false, "text": {"location": {"latitude": 34.04481184664412, "longitude": -118.30783339686604},
```

Comment: Is this not a json file? if you share whole file or a proper piece of the file, then it would be easier to tell.

Comment: no, its a piece of a text file, from lxml.html and requests. I just need to be able to extract these pieces from it:
{"location": {"latitude": a , "longitude": b },
where a and b could be different float numbers

Comment: Say you do extract those values from the large string, how would you then organize them into something useful, or know which elements each of the values of latitude and longitude belong to? Parsing the string into a dictionary or load it into a json object would make that more manageable.

Comment: As long as I get this sub string out, {"location": {"latitude": a , "longitude": b },  its easy to extract different values and store them. I just need a neat way of extracting these sub-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will give you all the `locations`

```
import re
[a.start() for a in re.finditer('"location"', mystr)]
```

The output will be: `[x1 x2 x3 ... xn]` where `xi` is the first character of `"location"` in `mystr`.

Then, for each value that is returned, you can get the data between first `{` and `}`.

Note that, this data looks like *Yelp business dataset*. I've played with this data before and I remember this had some json files that you can do direct access the location information of each business without string search.

**Edit for Yelp business date:** 
As far as I remember,, the list you are looking at is a list of dictionaries.

You will first read whole file into a list. There is one element for each business.

```
 for busn in list:
      busn['location'] -> this will give you the location dictionary
      busn['location']['lattitude'] will give you lattitude of the business.
```

You may need to check if the business have location information. You can do it as follows:

```
 if 'location' in busn: 
        busn['location']
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Could you please direct me to how to get and use the Json file? yes it is yelp's data.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check